# passing variables between python and C++ (embedding, not extending)

Tags: python, c++, embedding

I'm just starting, so please don't paste me 200 lines of code to convert an int. I need to keep it simple with as few obscure commands as possible.

I spent HOURS trying to find an example of something as entry level as possible, finding nothing. I've tried countless things PyArg_ParseTuple, PyArg_Parse, Py_BuildValue, and so many more. Probably wrong syntax but ALL the documentation has NO EXAMPLES. I got extremely frustrated spending hours after something that should be extremely trivial.

I'm simply trying to embed a tiny python function in C++ code. To keep things as barebone as possible, I just want to pass a C int named a1 to a python function, add it to b1, take the return value and print it from C++ with cout.

So:

```
PyObject *pmod1;
int a1 = 20; 
int cresult = 0;
int b1 = 0;

Py_Initialize();
pmod1 = PyImport_ImportModule("usermod");

(GAP HERE)

std::cout << cresult << " " << a1 << " " << b1;

Py_Finalize();
```

The usermod.py is:

```
pythb1 = 5;

def ThisFunc(a,b):
  result = a+b
  return result
```

That's all. I want to pass the a1 C-int to Thisfunc a, pythb1 to b, then take the "result" to assign its value to "cresult", and print it with a cout. I also would like to read pythb1 from the python function to put that value in b1.

So the cout output would be: 25 20 5

Can someone help, with the most straight to the point and simple code?
I need to fill that gap in the C++ code...

Between the (many) things I tried there's:
`long a1(PyLong_AsLong(pmod3));`

Where pmod3 is a python object. This crashes the program with no error message.

Editing again, and again:
I managed to achieve something on my own. I was able to adapt an example I found in a book, otherwise there's nothing on the internet I was able to find that was helpful...

AND DONE, after a million of tries and edits. This compiles. I have no idea if it's how it's suppose to work, but it does what I want.

It's also tricky because if you set the name of a variable wrong the compiler doesn't give any error message, it doesn't behave like C++ code.

```
PyObject *pmod, *pdict, *pvar, *presult, *pa1;
long a1 = 20, b1, cresult; 

Py_Initialize();

pmod = PyImport_ImportModule("usermod");
pdict = PyModule_GetDict(pmod);
pvar = PyRun_String("pythb1", Py_eval_input, pdict, pdict); // this reads the pthb1 set in the python script, and puts it in pvar object

if(PyLong_Check(pvar)){
  b1 = (PyLong_AsLong(pvar)); // this copies the python object pthb1/pvar into b1 C long, it seems there are only long types in python
}

pa1 = (PyLong_FromLong(a1)); // this creates a python object from a C long

PyObject_SetAttrString(pmod, "X1", pa1);
PyObject_SetAttrString(pmod, "X2", pvar);
presult = PyRun_String("ThisFunc(X1,X2)", Py_eval_input, pdict, pdict);

if(PyLong_Check(presult)){
  cresult = (PyLong_AsLong(presult)); 
}

std::cout << cresult << " " << a1 << " " << b1 << std::endl;

Py_DECREF(pmod); // cleaning
Py_DECREF(pvar);
Py_DECREF(presult);
Py_DECREF(pa1);

Py_Finalize();
```

Output: 25 20 5, exactly as expected.

So it can absolutely be done. There are just no examples out there, for some mysterious reason.

I just wish there was more and better documentation for all this...

Comment: So you are embedding the Python interpreter into a C++ application then calling a pure Python function. What are you trying to do that is not in the [Pure Embedding](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) section of the Python documentation?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the proper way but you can do this from most languages with most of interpreted languages:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define RESULT_MAX_LENGTH 256

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;

  char cmd[256];
  sprintf(cmd, "python -c \"import usermod; print(usermod.Thisfunc(%d, %d))\"", a, b);

  //printf("%s", cmd);

  FILE * fp = popen(cmd, "r");

  char result[RESULT_MAX_LENGTH];
  while (fgets(result, RESULT_MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL)
    printf("%s", result);

  return 0;
}
```

For the proper way of embedding Python in C, Daniel Dearlove is right, follow instructions here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html